# NumPy - slow double for loop for heatmap color calculation

Tags: python, numpy, heatmap

In the following code I wanted to generate a color heatmap (w x h x 3) based on the values of a NumPy 2-d array, in the range [-1; 1], and, unsurprisingly, it is really slow on large arrays (10000 x 10000) compared to the rest of the program, which uses NumPy numerical operations. Colors are in the [B, G, R] format.

```
def img_to_heatmap(arr):
    height, width = arr.shape
    heatmap = np.zeros((height, width, 3))
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            val = arr[i,j]
            if(val < 0): # [-1 to 0)
                val += 1
                heatmap[i,j,:] = [0, val * 255, 255]     # red -> yellow
            else:  # [0 to 1]
                heatmap[i,j,:] = [0, 255, 255 - 255*val] # yellow -> green 

    return heatmap
```

How can this code run faster while using the exact same color map? I know OpenCV has built-in heatmap calculations, but not the exact color map I want.

Comment: could you explain what the `red->yellow` comments are? as i understand, your input is only a 2d matrix. if would be good if you could explain what your end goal is with this code. what does the -1, 0, 1 represent, and how are you trying to display them each?

Comment: i am expecting a color image (width x height x 3 array) with a linear change in color based on the input pixel. 
For example, -1 will display full bright red, -0.5 orange, 0 yellow, 0.5 lime, 1 green

Comment: The values represent the NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index) computed from Sentinel-2 satellite multispectral images. The end goal would be displaying the vegetation heatmap of a specific area.

Comment: let me know if my approach below helps you solve your problem. if yes then do mark the answer. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per your comment under your question - `For example, -1 will display full bright red, -0.5 orange, 0 yellow, 0.5 lime, 1 green`

IIUC, you are trying to display a large matrix as a heatmap where you can set the color maps at fixed static values but, the color mixing should happen automatically. For example - if you have set 0 as yellow, `1` as green, then `0.5` should have a lemon-green color.

### Approach 1: Numpy first then plot

If you are interested in only the matrix manipulated, then you can do this simply by using numpy -

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def heatmap_raw(arr):
    scale = np.interp(arr, (-1, 1), (0, 1))         #convert -1 to 1 -> 0 to 1
    R = np.where((1-scale)>=0.5,255,255*(1-scale))  #red layer
    G = np.where(scale<0.5,255*scale,255)           #green layer
    B = np.zeros_like(arr)                          #blue layer

    #stack, transpose and round
    raw = np.round(np.stack([R, G, B])).transpose(1,2,0).astype(np.uint8)
    return raw

arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])
print(heatmap_raw(arr))
plt.imshow(heatmap_raw(arr))
```

```
# RGB values (H,W,3) array shape
array([[[255.,   0.,   0.],   #<- -1 is red
        [255.,  64.,   0.],   #<- -0.5 is orange
        [255., 255.,   0.],   #<- 0 is yellow
        [ 64., 255.,   0.],   #<- 0.5 is lemon green
        [  0., 255.,   0.]]]) #<- 1 is green
```

[image]

**Benchmark for a (10000,10000) array -**

```
%%timeit
arr = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10000,10000))
heatmap_raw(arr)
```

```
14.5 s ± 924 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

### Approach 2: Plotting only using custom cmap

If your goal ultimately is to visualize, you can directly jump to creating a custom `CMAP` in `matplotlib` and then plot the heatmap using `seaborn`. Note, this takes a bit of time to render but that is expected.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def heatmap_custom(arr):
    cvals  = [-1, 0, 1]                #<- only define colors for..
    clrs = ["red","yellow","green"]    #<- ..the key checkpoints

    norm = plt.Normalize(min(cvals),max(cvals))
    tuples = list(zip(map(norm,cvals), clrs))
    cmap = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", tuples)

    sns.heatmap(arr, cmap=cmap)

arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])  #<- dummy array with the example you mentioned
heatmap_custom(arr)
```

[image]

> `For example, -1 will display full bright red, -0.5 orange, 0 yellow, 0.5 lime, 1 green`

Another example -

```py
arr = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(50,50))
heatmap_custom(arr)
```

[image]

Example with (10000, 10000) shaped matrix -

```
arr = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(10000,10000))
heatmap_custom(arr)
```

[image]

---

## Bonus (additional experimentation)

I was playing around with some transformations that can better help distinguish colors when building a heatmap. Here is the updated code and experimental results for anyone who is interested!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Transformations to better distinguish color gradient
sinfx = lambda x: np.sin(2*x)
cubefx = lambda x: np.power(x, 3)
expfx = lambda x: np.exp(x)
customfx = lambda x: 1-np.exp(-1*x)

def heatmap_raw(arr, transform = False, fx=None):
    """
    Input: np.array(m,n), 2D matrix with values
    Output: np.array(m,n,3) with values ranging from 0 to 255

    Additional Parameters:
        - transform (Optional) -> Bool
        - fx (Optional) -> transformation function

    Create a heatmap matrix (RGB) shaped (m,n,3) as an image tensor.
        1. Applies any transformation (Optional)
        2. Normalizes distribution to 0 to 1 scale for multiplications
        3. Applies R, G, B conditions based on custom logic
        4. Stacks, Round, Transposes the output before returning 
    """
    
    #Normalize (after applying transformation (optional))
    if transform == True:
        transformed = fx(arr)
        scale = np.interp(transformed, (transformed.min(), transformed.max()), (0, 1))
    else:
        scale = np.interp(arr, (arr.min(), arr.max()), (0, 1))
    
    #Create custom R, G, B based on rules
    R = np.where((1-scale)>=0.5,255,255*(1-scale))           #red layer
    G = np.where(scale<0.5,255*scale,255)                    #green layer
    B = np.zeros_like(arr)                                   #blue layer

    #Stack, Round and Transpose
    raw = np.round(np.stack([R, G, B])).transpose(1,2,0).astype(np.uint8)
    return raw
```

Experiment without a transformation -

```py
# Plotting transformations with their relation to original
arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])
scale = np.interp(arr, (-1, 1), (0, 1))
plt.plot(arr[0], scale[0])
plt.show()

#Heatmap scale
output = heatmap_raw(arr)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Experiment with `sin(2*x)` -

```py
# Plotting transformations with their relation to original
arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])
scale = sinfx(arr)
plt.plot(arr[0], scale[0])
plt.show()

#Heatmap scale
output = heatmap_raw(arr, transform=True, fx=sinfx)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Experiment with `cube(x)` -

```py
# Plotting transformations with their relation to original
arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])
scale = cubefx(arr)
plt.plot(arr[0], scale[0])
plt.show()

#Heatmap scale
output = heatmap_raw(arr, transform=True, fx=cubefx)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Experiment with `exp(x)` -

```py
# Plotting transformations with their relation to original
arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])
scale = expfx(arr)
plt.plot(arr[0], scale[0])
plt.show()

#Heatmap scale
output = heatmap_raw(arr, transform=True, fx=expfx)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Experiment with `1-exp(-x)` -

```py
# Plotting transformations with their relation to original
arr = np.array([[-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]])
scale = customfx(arr)
plt.plot(arr[0], scale[0])
plt.show()

#Heatmap scale
output = heatmap_raw(arr, transform=True, fx=customfx)
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `cube(x)` really helps distinguish the extreme values due to the nature of its distribution.

Comment: Thank you for all the detailed suggestions, it runs much better now!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `np.where` to find the index and vectorize your loops:

```
def img_to_heatmap1(arr):
    height, width = arr.shape
    heatmap = np.zeros((height * width, 3))
    heatmap[:, 1:] = 255
    arr = arr.reshape(-1)
    idx = np.where(arr < 0)
    
    nidx = np.where(arr >= 0)
    heatmap[idx, 1] = 255 * (arr[idx] + 1)
    heatmap[nidx, 2] -= 255 * arr[nidx] 

    return heatmap.reshape((height , width, 3))
```

for an image of 1K x 1K this will be roughly 20X speedup.